# Mootools accordian remote trigger in Joomla

Tags: joomla, triggers, mootools, accordion

I'm trying to customise the Joomla 2.5 Accordion contacts page to add a clickable map to trigger the accordion and I'm struggling. The accordion part works fine, and the map works fine with clickable areas, but I can't link the two.

The mootools accordion script that triggers the accordian is this (pretty standard Joomla contacts page version exept I added 'var OfficeAccordian =' on line 2:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
    var OfficeAccordian = new Fx.Accordion(
        $$('div#contact-slider.pane-sliders > .panel > h3.pane-toggler'), 
        $$('div#contact-slider.pane-sliders > .panel > div.pane-slider'), {
        onActive: function(toggler, i) {
            toggler.addClass('pane-toggler-down');
            toggler.removeClass('pane-toggler');i.addClass('pane-down');
            i.removeClass('pane-hide');
            Cookie.write('jpanesliders_contact-slider',$$('div#contact-slider.pane-sliders > .panel > h3').indexOf(toggler));
        },
        onBackground: function(toggler, i) {
            toggler.addClass('pane-toggler');
            toggler.removeClass('pane-toggler-down');
            i.addClass('pane-hide');i.removeClass('pane-down');
            if($$('div#contact-slider.pane-sliders > .panel > h3').length==$$('div#contact-slider.pane-sliders > .panel > h3.pane-toggler').length)
                Cookie.write('jpanesliders_contact-slider',-1);
        },
        duration: 300,
        opacity: false,
        alwaysHide: true
    }); 
});
```

but the script I need to simulate a click on the accordion trigger when I click a link on the map (standard anchor button in a list) is beyond me. I've had a go at adapting a few examples from various websites, but none have worked. My javascript skills are not good enough yet to know why they aren't working or how to fix them.
(I'm not sure it needs to be mootools as I have mootools & jquery both loaded & working on the site)

Comment: Did you get this working? If the answer under helped, please click to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The Fx.Accordion has an interface (API of methods the instance exposes so you can control it).

All it takes is reading the manual:

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion#Fx-Accordion:display

```
OfficeAccordian.display(2);
```

if that is not enough, you read the source code:

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-more/blob/master/Source/Fx/Fx.Accordion.js#L157

this reveals you can pass a second argument to `.display` as boolean to use fx or not.

p.s. this is not how you spell accordion (`OfficeAccordian`). :)

Comment: Afternoon, Thanks for the reply. I had tried using 'display' but I couldn't get it working. Perhaps I need to write a simpler test page & get that working first. I did notice I'd spelt accordion incorrectly (I have a blind spot on that word for some reason, even though I know it I always do it wrong) I changed it in the text, but missed it in the code.